# How to convert str to beautiful soup tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have two htmls that look like this:

```
<h3>
First heading 
</h3>
<ol>
<li>
hi
</li>
</ol>
<h3>
Second 
</h3>
<ol>
<li>
second
</li>
</ol>
```

Document 2

```
<h3>
First heading 
</h3>
<ol>
<li>
hello
</li>
</ol>
<h3>
Second 
</h3>
<ol>
<li>
second to second
</li>
</ol>
```

I need to append li from second document to html of first document under relevant h3.
This is my code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
h3_tags = soup.find_all('h3')
ol_tags = [each_h3.find_next('ol') for each_h3 in h3_tags]


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string_new)
h3_tags_new = soup.find_all('h3')
ol_tags_new = [each_h3.find_next('ol') for each_h3 in h3_tags_new]

countries_old = []
countries_new = []
html_new = ""
for i in h3_tags:
    countries_old.append(i.text)
for i in h3_tags_new:
    countries_new.append(i.text)

for country in countries_new:
    idx = countries_old.index(country)
    tag = str(ol_tags[idx])

    tag = tag[:-5]
    tag = tag[4:]
    idx_new = countries_new.index(country)
    tag_new = str(ol_tags_new[idx_new])

    tag_new = tag_new[:-5]
    tag_new = tag_new[4:]
    tag = "<ol>" + tag + tag_new + "</ol>"
    ol_tags[idx] = tag

    html_new += h3_tags[idx]
    html_new += tag


with open("check.html", "w", encoding="utf8") as html_file:
    html_file.write(html_new)
    html_file.close()

import pypandoc
output = pypandoc.convert(source='check.html', format='html', to='docx', outputfile='test.docx', extra_args=["-M2GB", "+RTS", "-K64m", "-RTS"])
```

This code takes h3 from second document checks its index and from same index takes the value from ol of second document.  It then removes ol tags from these and concatenate these two together. It keeps storing these in html_file. But when I concatenate ol with h3 it gives this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Tag") to str
```

Edit:
expected output:

```
<h3>
First heading 
</h3>
<ol>
<li>
hello
</li>
<li>
hi
</li>
</ol>
<h3>
Second 
</h3>
<ol>
<li>
second to second
</li>
<li>
second
</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html1 = """
<h3>
First heading 
</h3>
<ol>
<li>
hi
</li>
</ol>
<h3>
Second 
</h3>
<ol>
<li>
second
</li>
</ol>
"""

html2 = """
<h3>
First heading 
</h3>
<ol>
<li>
hello
</li>
</ol>
<h3>
Second 
</h3>
<ol>
<li>
second to second
</li>
</ol>
"""

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html1, "html.parser")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2, "html.parser")

for li in soup2.select("h3 + ol > li"):
    h3_text = li.find_previous("h3").get_text(strip=True)
    h3_soup1 = soup1.find("h3", text=lambda t: h3_text in t)
    if not h3_soup1:
        continue
    h3_soup1.find_next("ol").insert(0, li)

print(soup1.prettify())
```

Prints:

```html
<h3>
 First heading
</h3>
<ol>
 <li>
  hello
 </li>
 <li>
  hi
 </li>
</ol>
<h3>
 Second
</h3>
<ol>
 <li>
  second to second
 </li>
 <li>
  second
 </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: h3_soup1 = soup1.find("h3", text=lambda t: h3_text in t)
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: @hannahmontanna Try `h3_soup1 = soup1.find("h3", text=lambda t: t and h3_text in t)`

Comment: It worked quite well. Didn't think code will be this pythonic and simple. Thank you!